# Is there an equivalent to the GL_SCISSOR method in OpenGL available in plain Java?

Tags: java

I am developing a simple java 2D game and creating a diagonal animation but it doesn't seem to work as anticipated, when working with OpenGL, I remember an easy fix to this would to just use a GL_SCISSOR test around the bounds of the animation 'frame' (in my case just a rect), so it only displays as expected, however I've made this game in plain java and would be a pain to port over to LWJGL. Is there an equivalent to this method in plain java?

Comment: Such operation is more often called *clipping* in non-accelerated graphics. Look for calls like `setClip`, `clipRect` or something similar, depending on the API you use.

Comment: @tevemadar thank you so much! Worked like a charm!